# Convert SHA1 to base64

Tags: php

can someone help with this thing that is driving me crazy? on https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en and https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

I want to get this output on my PHP script like the above sites----->afE/gGTQDVy64Mres5m26KbDMU4=

```
$str = '69F13F8064D00D5CBAE0CADEB399B6E8A6C3314E';
echo base64_encode($str);
```

but my output is-------->

```
NjlGMTNGODA2NEQwMEQ1Q0JBRTBDQURFQjM5OUI2RThBNkMzMzE0RQ==
```

Comment: base64_encode converts a string, you want to convert a hex number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does `echo base64_encode(hex2bin('69F13F8064D00D5CBAE0CADEB399B6E8A6C3314E'));` work for you?

I tested this here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9715207a2edbf15ca54c89cbf9c79559bcfcd76e